# Find Largest Drive, NSIS installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I am completely new to NSIS installer script, I want to set the install directory to the largest disk on the computer. Can anyone guide me how to do it.

Comment: It usually makes more sense to use $ProgramFiles\YourApp as the default...

Comment: You should also remember that volumes can be mounted in a folder on NTFS so just checking drive letters might not find the largest volume...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
System::Call 'kernel32::GetLogicalDrives()i.r0'
StrCpy $1 $windir 3 ; Fallback if things go wrong
StrCpy $2 0
StrCpy $4 65 ; 'A'
loop:
    IntOp $3 $0 & 1
    ${If} $3 <> 0
        IntFmt $3 "%c:\" $4
        System::Call 'kernel32::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(tr3,*l.r5,*l,*l)i'
        ${If} $5 L> $2
            StrCpy $2 $5
            StrCpy $1 $3
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $4 $4 + 1
    IntOp $0 $0 >> 1
    StrCmp $0 0 "" loop
StrCpy $InstDir "$1" ;You should probably append something to the path here, you cannot install to the root of a drive by default
```

Put it in .onInit or the pre callback for your directory page...

Comment: This code checks the free space because it makes more sense for an installer to do it this way and it will avoid read-only volumes...

Comment: Great this works!!! I am done with installation part. After installing the executable, I need to prompt user to insert another DVD to install a utility. Can you guide me how to do it

Comment: If it is unrelated to this question then you should ask a new question (And accept this answer if it was correct)

Comment: ${If} $3 <> 0; what does this statement do?

Comment: If $3 is a number other than 0 then... (We only want the drive letters that are valid)