# NSIS: install new product

Tags: installation, nsis

I have two product to install one is server utility and other is client utility. I am writing installation script for server utility. Just after installing the server utility and before rebooting the computer I want to prompt user to insert DVD to install client utility.
I am new to NSIS scripting, can any one tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to just use a `MessageBox` asking the user if they want to install this thing, if they say yes then you can use some of [your other code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992620/3501), just replace the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx part with some code that checks if it is the correct disc ([IfFileExists](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#iffileexists) etc). If the correct disc is not found you should `goto` back to the MessageBox so the user can try again or cancel...